# Check All checkbox not working across the table pagination razer mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a checkall checkbox for the table but the table has pagination and DOM only gets the elements currently showing on the page. my implementation is not working on other paginations. how can we achieve this task?
.cshtml code

```
 <table id="instruments" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover smart-form has-tickbox" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input id="chkAffectCheckboxGroup" type="checkbox" />                                                                 
                </th>
                                                                
                <th data-class="expand" style="white-space: nowrap">@Model.idResource</th>
                <th data-hide="phone" style="white-space: nowrap">@Model.SResource</th>
                <th data-hide="phone" style="white-space: nowrap">@Model.LocationResource</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Instruments.Count; i++)
            {
                var values = Model.Instruments[i].Value.Split('~');
                var status = values.Length > 0 ? values[0] : "";
                var location = values.Length > 1 ? values[1] : "";
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="checkbox">                                                                                           
                          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Instruments[i].Selected, new { @class = "chkInst" })
                          <i></i>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td><label>@Model.Instruments[i].Text</label></td>
                    <td><label>@status</label></td>
                    <td><label>@location</label></td>
                </tr>
                                                            }
        </tbody>
   </table>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(
            console.log("jquery called"),
            manageCheckboxGroup('chkAffectCheckboxGroup', 'chkInst')
        );
```

JavaScript Code

```
function manageCheckboxGroup(masterCheckboxId, slaveCheckboxesClass) {

            $("#" + masterCheckboxId).click(function () {
                $("." + slaveCheckboxesClass).prop('checked', this.checked);
            });

            $("." + slaveCheckboxesClass).click(function () {
                if (!this.checked) {
                    $("#" + masterCheckboxId).prop('checked', false);
                }
                else if ($("." + slaveCheckboxesClass).length == $("." + slaveCheckboxesClass + ":checked").length) {
                    $("#" + masterCheckboxId).prop('checked', true);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you pl share your `output` vs `expected output`?

Comment: @Moeez I have a table with pagination 1 2 3. When i move page 1 to 2 the selection of the checkboxes don't retain. as the dom only shows the elements which are shown on the page 1 so first 10 rows one the page 1 is selected the next 10 rows on the page 2 are not selected.